# How do i use JSON to make a dynamic Sidebar in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, next.js

```
[
  {
    "type": "root",
    "children": [
      {
        "type": "file",
        "route": "Open-EdTech/AWS-Associate-Notes/EC2.md",
        "title": "EC2",
        "path": "/Users/matthewcaseres/Documents/GitHub/AWS-Associate-Notes/EC2.md",
        "treePath": [0],
        "children": [
            {
                        "title": "Purpose/Design",
                        "route": "Open-EdTech/next-mdx-books/about.md/#purposedesign",
                        "type": "heading",
                        "treePath": [0,0]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Installation",
                        "route": "Open-EdTech/next-mdx-books/about.md/#installation",
                        "type": "heading",
                        "treePath": [0,1]
                    }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "file",
        "route": "Open-EdTech/AWS-Associate-Notes/VPC.md",
        "title": "VPC",
        "path": "/Users/matthewcaseres/Documents/GitHub/AWS-Associate-Notes/VPC.md",
        "treePath": [1]
      },
      {
        "type": "file",
        "route": "Open-EdTech/AWS-Associate-Notes/S3.md",
        "title": "S3",
        "path": "/Users/matthewcaseres/Documents/GitHub/AWS-Associate-Notes/S3.md",
        "treePath": [2]
      },
      {
        "type": "file",
        "route": "Open-EdTech/AWS-Associate-Notes/Databases.md",
        "title": "Databases",
        "path": "/Users/matthewcaseres/Documents/GitHub/AWS-Associate-Notes/Databases.md",
        "treePath": [3]
      },
      {
        "type": "file",
        "route": "Open-EdTech/AWS-Associate-Notes/Global-Infrastructure.md",
        "title": "AWS Global Infrastructure",
        "path": "/Users/matthewcaseres/Documents/GitHub/AWS-Associate-Notes/Global-Infrastructure.md",
        "treePath": [4]
      },
      {
        "type": "file",
        "route": "Open-EdTech/AWS-Associate-Notes/SNS.md",
        "title": "SNS",
        "path": "/Users/matthewcaseres/Documents/GitHub/AWS-Associate-Notes/SNS.md",
        "treePath": [5]
      },
      {
        "type": "file",
        "route": "Open-EdTech/AWS-Associate-Notes/SQS.md",
        "title": "SQS",
        "path": "/Users/matthewcaseres/Documents/GitHub/AWS-Associate-Notes/SQS.md",
        "treePath": [6]
      }
    ],
    "title": "AWS Solutions Architect Associate Notes",
    "treePath": []
  }
]
```

I have been trying to learn how to make a Side-Navigation or sidebar from JSON, a sidebar that has a multilevel menu, unfortunately, there are no clear references/tutorials/materials so whoever has an idea, kindly assist me and other nextjs learners for to know how to do this for posterity.

Comment: The problem is there is no clear references on how to create a sidebar from json, and i would like to know how to do it, guidelines would also do

Comment: Because that is not how programming guides usually work. Do you know how to make a sidebar? If not, learn that first. Then, do you know how to parse json? If not, learn that too. Then use your knowledge to combine these into what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a  component with a title on top and a map function that goes over the array of children and renders a button for each loading in your JSON data.

The button component should also have the possibility to map over another level of children and map those under it aswell.

You could also take a look at a side navigation package like: https://reactjsexample.com/minimal-side-navigation-component-for-react/